# Obtaining kinematic and stress conditions on a free surface, in boundary value problem?

Tags: boundary-value-problem, fluid-dynamics, kinematics

Could anyone comment how the conditions 2.4 and 2.5 were obtained in attached text piece?

These conditions are kinematic and stress conditions on a free surface of a fluid flow. Authors do not provide explanation.

[image]

Source: https://ac.els-cdn.com/089571779390215K/1-s2.0-089571779390215K-main.pdf?_tid=spdf-98b088d4-1f06-4bc3-820f-a382e0e18219&acdnat=1519767957_b8ddcf3a389abe96112ee67fea01c0bb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The free surface is $r=R(x,t)$, which can be rewritten as the zero level set $F(x,r,t) = r-R(x,t) = 0$. Since fluid particles on the free surface must remain on the free surface (this is essentially the no-penetration boundary condition), it follows that the material derivative of $F(x,r,t)$ must be zero, i.e. 
$$ \frac{DF}{Dt} = \frac{\partial F}{\partial t} + (u,v)\cdot\nabla F = 0 $$
Computing and substituting all the necessary partial derivatives of $F$ into this equation then yields the kinematic condition (2.4). For the (normal) stress boundary condition, it doesn't seem like what I have in mind but perhaps you can figure it out if I explain the terms in equation (2.5)? The vector $(-R_x,1)$ is the (outward) normal vector of the free surface and $R$ in this case corresponds to the radius of curvature. The matrix on the left, if you look close enough, is actually the Newtonian stress tensor.